# Javascript HTML right-click browser menu? Help with getting example working

Tags: javascript, html

i'm trying to get the following example set up on my computer:

http://deluxe-menu.com/popup-mode-sample.html

I've right clicked for the source code, copied the HTML into a file on my local computer and have saved the 5 javascript files (dmenu,data,add,data-popup-mode,data-popup-mode2).js into the same folder.

I have also swapped their image for one of my own which is located in the same directory.

When i right click my image it says

Error: dm_popup is not defined

However, i cannot seem to find where this has been declared. Can someone please help?

EDIT: I've also copied over the css files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also need the `dmenu_popup.js` file, that function you need is included inside. It seems to be loaded by `dmenu.js`, that explains why you haven't seen it.

Comment: Thanks, where did you see that file listed? I went through the HTML and searched for .js and only found 5 .js files, not including that.

Comment: I saw it using Chrome tool (Script tab), but you can do the same using Firebug in Firefox (network tab). If you do not use that tool, you should consider starting right now :)